# I am having problem with initialization of parallelization in Mathematica

Tags: parallelization, mathematica-online

I have been using parallel computing in Mathematica for a couple of months. Today suddenly, parallel kernels are not starting. Can anyone tell me what can be the potential reason?

```
weights3 =  ParallelTable[Sum[a3[[Position[b3, level3[[i]]][[j, 1]]]],
 {j,1,Length[Position[b3, level3[[i]]]]}], {i, 1, Length[level3]}];
```

Here, I received these errors:

LinkObject::linkd: Unable to communicate with closed link LinkObject["C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.1\WolframKernel" -noinit -noicon -subkernel -wstp,887,10].

LinkObject::linkd: Unable to communicate with closed link LinkObject["C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.1\WolframKernel" -noinit -noicon -subkernel -wstp,888,11].

LinkObject::linkd: Unable to communicate with closed link LinkObject["C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.1\WolframKernel" -noinit -noicon -subkernel -wstp,889,12].

General::stop: Further output of LinkObject::linkd will be suppressed during this calculation.

Parallel`Developer`ConnectKernel::failinit: 4 of 4 kernels failed to initialize.

ParallelTable::nopar: No parallel kernels available; proceeding with sequential evaluation.

The code is perfect because it worked for me. I think there may be some technical problem. Can anyone help me in this point?

Comment: If you haven't changed anything in your configuration, have you tried restarting everything (mma, computer, etc) and trying again? If you have changed something (updates, settings...), then please let us know.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose a problem that can't be reproduced. A complete code would help. And please clarify how [tag:mathematica-online] is related to your problem. I don't seem to able to use parallelization at wolframcloud.com (different error messages), so the system you use must be different from mine.